# How to Set a Condition via Page Template Name in WP Cron Job?

Tags: wp-cron, cron

I have created a Cron Job Function. But, I can't set a condition for Cron Job. Basically I want Cron Job need to work if the Template File Name is `page-delete.php` So, How can I set Condition using Template Name?

---

```php
// custom_schedules_create
function custom_schedules_create( $schedules ) {
    $schedules['every_three_minutes'] = array(
            'interval'  => 180,
            'display'   => __( 'Every 3 Minutes', 'textdomain' )
    );
    return $schedules;
}
add_filter( 'cron_schedules', 'custom_schedules_create' );

// custom_3minutes_event
if ( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'custom_3minutes_event' ) ) {
    $myLocalGMTTimeEvent = time() + 6*60*60;
    wp_schedule_event( $myLocalGMTTimeEvent, 'every_three_minutes', 'custom_3minutes_event' );    
}
add_action( 'custom_3minutes_event', 'this_funtion_will_work' );  

// this_funtion_will_work
function this_funtion_will_work() {
    if ( is_page_template('page-delete.php') /* Checking If Page from this "page-delete.php" template */ ) {
        $the_query = get_posts( array(
            'post_type'      => 'page',
            'post_status'    => 'publish',
        ));
        foreach($the_query as $single_post) {
            $id=$single_post->ID;
            $myLocalGMTTime = 6*60*60;
            $getLocalGMTTime = time() + $myLocalGMTTime;
            $getLocalGMTDate = date('H:i', $getLocalGMTTime);
            if($getLocalGMTDate == '18:00'){
                $update_post = array(
                    'ID'            => $id,
                    'post_status'   =>  'private'
                );
                wp_update_post($update_post);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This would work better if it used a `WP_Query` loop instead of a `get_posts` loop

Comment: kindly can you edit the code? I will helpful for me.

Comment: What do you mean "work if the Template File Name is page-delete.php"? You only want the cron job to run while that template is open? Or you only want to query posts using that template inside the cron job?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i can able to achieve it.

```
// custom_schedules_create
function custom_schedules_create( $schedules ) {
    $schedules['every_three_minutes'] = array(
            'interval'  => 180,
            'display'   => __( 'Every 3 Minutes', 'textdomain' )
    );
    return $schedules;
}
add_filter( 'cron_schedules', 'custom_schedules_create' );

// custom_3minutes_event
if ( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'custom_3minutes_event' ) ) {
    $myLocalGMTTimeEvent = time() + 6*60*60;
    wp_schedule_event( $myLocalGMTTimeEvent, 'every_three_minutes', 'custom_3minutes_event' );    
}
add_action( 'custom_3minutes_event', 'this_funtion_will_work' );  

// this_funtion_will_work
function this_funtion_will_work() {
    $the_query = get_posts( array(
        'post_type'      => 'page',
        'post_status'    => 'publish',
    ));
    foreach($the_query as $single_post) {
        $id = $single_post->ID;
        $myLocalGMTTime = 6*60*60;
        $getLocalGMTTime = time() + $myLocalGMTTime;
        $getLocalGMTDate = date('H:i', $getLocalGMTTime);
        $get_template = get_post_meta( $id, '_wp_page_template', true );
        if( ( $getLocalGMTDate == '18:00' ) && ( 'page-delete.php' == $get_template )){
            $update_post = array(
                'ID'            => $id,
                'post_status'   =>  'private'
            );
            wp_update_post($update_post);
        }
    }
}
```